# Exe (console application) trouble shooting

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I am working on data feeding console application. It feeds the xml files (data in form of xml file) from a directory to a portfolio application. It processes files one by one in for loop depends on file count.

When I run the exe of this application sometimes it suddenly stops in between because of some unknown error. Though, I have used logging mechanism and error handling. What should I do so that it should not crash (stop) in between until all the files have been processed.

Comment: You'd need to show us some code.

Comment: You need more logging strings so you know precisely in your code where the program stops.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an unknown exception thrown that is not caught. You could try to add a global exception handler ([via this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/637425)) and log that exception. But that could still lead to your program stopping but at least you catch all the exceptions so you can debug better.