# C# SQL Server update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I try to update a sqldatabase server. I did this earlier with the buildin "Local Database" in visual studio. B
I did this (in short)

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder cb;
cb = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds1, "Alarmen");
```

But the builtin database did not meet the requirements. I had to use Microsoft SQL server 2005.
I tried to do this also, but that did not work.
First i fill a database set from the database with the following commands:\

```
fillDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLExpress;database=Alarmen;integrated Security=SSPI;");
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_alarmen";

    try
    {
        _con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("Database kon niet geopend worden " + ex);
    }

    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_alarmen";

        _cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _con);
        _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

        _dap.Fill(ds1, "Alarmen");

        foreach (DataRow drow in ds1.Tables["Alarmen"].Rows)
        {
            log.Info("Test");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        log.Info("Database lezen mislukt " + err);
    }

    try
    {
        _con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("Database sluiten mislukt " + ex);
    }
        _dap.Fill(ds1, "Alarmen");

        foreach (DataRow drow in ds1.Tables["Alarmen"].Rows)
        {
            log.Info("Test");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        log.Info("Database lezen mislukt " + err);
    }

    try
    {
        _con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("Database sluiten mislukt " + ex);
    }
}
```

Then i add rows and modify items in the dataset and try op update the changes in the database.

```
UpdateDatabase()
{
    SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLExpress;database=Alarmen;integrated Security=SSPI;");
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_alarmen";

    try
    {
        _con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("Database kon niet geopend worden " + ex);
    }

    try
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_alarmen", con);
        new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        //
        // Fill the DataAdapter with the values in the DataTable.
        //
 adapter.Fill(ds1);
        //
        // Insert the data table into the SQL database.
        //
adapter.Update(ds1);             
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       log.Info("Fill database failed " + e);
    }

    try
    {
        _con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("Database sluiten mislukt " + ex);
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors, but the database keeps being empty.

I now i should not use the "SELECT *" for security issues. I need to change that in the future.

I see i did not aks a real question. What did i do wrong in my code and how could i fix it.

Comment: Well, the first anti-pattern I can see in this code is that, if an exception is thrown when opening a connection, you report the error and then **carry on** attempting to use the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the input. This is something I can use. But i use the try-catch principal to see if there are errors. The problem is the errors are not trown. So i assume they do not give any errors.

Comment: Also, consider using `using` clause when opening a `SqlConnection` which will make handling of connections easier in case problems arise. See this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection).

Besides, you're using `try/catch` blocks only to log exception information without doing anything else. This is not a good practice - only catch an exception if you plan to do something about it (e.g. rollback). A better, cleaner way would be to use `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. Example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
adapter.Fill(ds1, "Alarmen")
```

and then

```
adapter.Update(ds1, "Alarmen");
```

See [this MS link for more info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now i got an other error. But i think it is unrelated to my question.