# How to handle the exceptions without using try catch in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

is there any other option .NET other than try catch to handle exceptions.?

Comment: Check this, It may help in your case 
[.NET Global exception handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application)

Comment: thank you. i think it will solve my problem