# Unhandled Exceptions and werfault

Tags: c#, exception, windows-error-reporting

Consider we have this snippet of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------finally-----");
    }
}
```

We have unhandled exception and `finally` block.

When `werfault` is enabled and I press `Cancel` when it is trying to "automatically solve problem" **finally block executes.**

[image]

But if I'm not pressing `Cancel` and in the next window clicking `Close The Program` **finally block doesn't execute.**

[image]

And finally when I disable `werfault` and click `Close Program` **finally block executes.**

[image]

I didn't find any documentation in c# spec that describes this situation. Also I found this on [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx):

> Execution of the finally block after an unhandled error depends on how
>   the exception unwind operation is triggered.

But there is no explanation, anyone can describe why this is happening ?

**Update 1**: I have tested it in .Net Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2.

Comment: This could be framework version specific. Which version do you use?

Comment: @ThomasWeller See updated question please:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WerFault.exe` ***terminates*** and kills the .NET *process* immediately due to an unhandled exception but when you disable `WerFault` Microsoft .NET Error Reporting somehow closes the application so that the `finally` block still is executed and does not terminate the *process*.

The best way to check that `WerFault.exe` terminates *process* immediately is the [`Event Viewer`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) (`Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.`).

> ```
> Application: ConsoleApplication3.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Exception
> Stack:
>    at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(System.String[])
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is there any documentation that WerFault.exe should terminate program immediately?

Answer (score 1):

**Werfault.exe** (Windows Error Reporting) is called for software targeting Framework 4 or greater.
 It does behave as you mention.
**Dw20.exe** (Dr Watson) is called for Framework 3.5 or below.
 It behaves correctly (*always call finally*).

The behaviour of these (non .net) programs are different. It may comes from the way Werfault produces its minidump (kill the program before finally) which is obviously buggy.

As some users have already noticed, [WerFault could be somewhat a "faulty" program](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2012/02/17/werfault-exe-windows-error-reporting-shortcomings/).

Anyway, for a developper, I don't think sending data to Microsoft about your "Console 9" application is relevant. [So you can safely disable the error reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx) :

> set HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/Windows Error Reporting/Disabled
>   to 1

As a conclusion, if you have some concern about privacy you wouldn't let Werfault send any data to Microsoft as [NSA could use it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("------finally-----");
        }
    }

    static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

i find it on:[.NET Global exception handler in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my question isn't to handle unhandled exceptions, I want to know why this is acting like this ?

Comment: You don't check for IsTerminating. And Console.Readline means interaction which is not needed if you're not in the debugger but running from command line