# Default exception handler body

Tags: c#, exception, console-application, tostring

I have a custom exception class, inherited from `Exception` and a console application where the exception is thrown. My custom exception overrides the `ToString()` method, but when the exception is thrown, the message and stack trace print to console, but the overridden `ToString()` method does not seem to be called.

I know how to create a default exception handler ([.NET Global exception handler in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application)). However, what is the body of the default handler for console application if the custom one is not specified?

Comment: Can you show your code where you're catching the unhandled exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve by overriding `.ToString()` method, but if you are trying to set a custom message I would recommend to use the constructor:

```
public class CustomException : Exception 
{
    public CustomException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }
}
```

or override `Message` property:

```
public class CustomException : Exception 
{
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return "Something bad happened";
        }
    }
}
```

Answering on the question about `UnhandledException event` - I believe that handlers are launched on `CLR` level when an unhandled exception is found for specific domain therefore it is quite impossible to look if there are default handlers on it. I guess that there is no point to even have those.