# How can I debug an "Index was out of range" exception? Or can I make VS enter debug mode when an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My issue is that I'm getting an `Index was out of range` exception thrown and I want to figure out exactly where this is happening and what the particular array and index is that is causing the error. I get simply step through my program to find it because the # of times that it uses the access operator `[]` is millions. So is there some way I can make my program "step back" and enter debug mode when the exception is thrown? I can't figure out how else to solve this except through brute force which could take many hours.

Here is a full code dump in case that helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StringSet
{


    class StringSet
    {

        private List<List<string>> _Buckets;
        public int NumStrings { get; private set; }

        public StringSet ( ) 
        {
            this._Buckets = new List<List<string>>();
            this.NumStrings = 0;
        }

        public StringSet ( string[] S )
        {
            // better way to do this?
            this._Buckets = new List<List<string>>();
            foreach ( string s in S ) this._Buckets.Add(new List<string>());
            foreach ( string s in S ) { this.Insert(s);  }
        }

        private int _GetBucketNumber ( string s, List<List<string>> Buckets )
        {
            //       s: string whose index to look up
            // Buckets: source buckets

            // disallow empty or NULL strings
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) { throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add empty or NULL string to set"); }
            if ( Buckets.Count == 0 ) { throw new ArgumentException("Tried to call _GetBucketNumber on empty bucket list"); }

            // Bernstein hash
            // http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx           
            int result = (int)s[0];
            for ( int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i ) { result = 33 * result + (int)s[i]; }
            return result % Buckets.Count;
        }

        private void _RehashIfNecessary ( )
        {
            // if the number of strings in the set exceeds the number of buckets, 
            // increase the number of buckets to either double its current size 
            // or the largest number of buckets possible, whichever is smaller
            if ( this.NumStrings > this._Buckets.Count )
            {
                List<List<string>> NewBuckets = new List<List<string>>(Math.Min(this._Buckets.Count * 2, Int32.MaxValue));
                foreach ( List<string> Bucket in this._Buckets )
                {
                    foreach ( string s in Bucket )
                    {
                        NewBuckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s, NewBuckets)].Add(s);
                    }
                }
                this._Buckets = NewBuckets;
            }
        }

        public void Insert ( string s )
        {
            // disallow empty or NULL strings
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) { throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add empty or NULL string to set"); }

            // Get bucket that string belongs in
            int k = this._GetBucketNumber(s, this._Buckets);
            if (k >= this._Buckets.Count) { Console.WriteLine("Found problem! GetBucketNumber return {0}, whichs is bigger or equal to than this._Buckets.Count={1}", k, this._Buckets.Count); }
            List<string> Bucket = this._Buckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s,this._Buckets)];
            // Add if not already there
            if ( Bucket.IndexOf(s) == -1 ) { Bucket.Add(s); }
            ++NumStrings; _RehashIfNecessary();
        }

        public bool Contains ( string s )
        {
            // returns true or false depending on whether s is a 
            // string currently in the set
            return (this._Buckets[this._GetBucketNumber(s,this._Buckets)].IndexOf(s) != -1);
        }

        public void RunPerformanceTest ( )
        {
            // tests string hash set against regular List<string> 
            // in terms of lookup

            // create list of all elements in hash set
            List<string> ListVersion = new List<string>(),
                                Copy = new List<string>();
            foreach ( List<string> Bucket in this._Buckets )
            {
                foreach ( string Str in Bucket )
                {
                    ListVersion.Add(Str);
                    Copy.Add(Str);
                }                    
            }

            // calculate average time to look up all elements
            Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();
            long tList = 0, tHset = 0; // ms
            foreach ( string Str in Copy )
            {
                // measure time to look up string in ordinary list
                Watch.Start();
                if ( ListVersion.Contains(Str) ) { }
                Watch.Stop();
                tList += Watch.ElapsedTicks;
                // now measure time to look up same string in my hash set
                Watch.Reset();
                Watch.Start();
                if ( this.Contains(Str) ) { }
                Watch.Stop();
                tHset += Watch.ElapsedTicks;
                Watch.Reset();
            }
            int n = Copy.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("Average ticks to look up in List: {0}", tList / n);
            Console.WriteLine("Average ticks to look up in hashset: {0}", tHset / n);
        }

        public void Print ( )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < this._Buckets.Count; ++i )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket {0}: {1}", i, string.Join(",",this._Buckets[i].ToArray()));
            }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {

            try
            {
                List<string> Words = new List<string>();
                Console.WriteLine("Reading dictionary words from text file into hash set ...");
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "testfiles\\dictionary.txt");
                string line; 
                while ( (line = file.ReadLine()) != null )
                {
                    Words.Add(line);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
                StringSet TestSet = new StringSet(Words.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine("Running performance test ...");
                TestSet.RunPerformanceTest();
                Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
            }
            catch ( Exception E )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured: {0}", E.Message);
            }
            Console.Read(); // just to keep console open
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect the stack trace of the exception when it happens. The problem is that you've caught `Exception` and then simply dumped the message, comment out the try/catch block and Visual Studio should stop when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Your try/catch is inadequate and just gets in the way of debugging your program.  [Do it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/17034).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make VS stop when the error is thrown.  It may vary a little between versions, but it's usually on the menu: Debug > Exceptions...

Then expand Common Language Runtime Exceptions - System and tick the box for your exception in the Thrown column