# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Project.exe

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

```
try
{
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, Password);

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filepath);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I really have no idea what I should do now, I searched through the Internet and couldn't find a way to fix the problem.

I am using `System.Net` as well, so it shouldn't be a problem.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Project.exe
>   Additional information: System Error.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: On which line you get the exception? Any more details? Can you add `catch (WebException wEx)
            {
                throw wEx;
            }` before your  `catch` and see if it gives more info? *Edit: Also include wEx.InnerException if possible.

Comment: Full exception stack please (of the `ex`, not of the exception you re-throw).

Comment: Have you tried writing a Global Exception Handler? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application - that'll at least give you some more information.

Comment: Also, right now you immediately re-throw any exception you receive, so (unless there's other error handling logic you haven't shown) *any* exception you get will be unhandled by definition - you're not handling it. Also, when re-throwing an exception you should use "throw;" rather than "throw exc;" to preserve the stack trace.

Comment: On a side note, you should never rethrow and execption like this since it will reset the stack trace. Instead simply write `throw;` in the catch block and .Net will rethrow the exception without wiping the stack trace.