# Configuration system failed to initialize - Settings Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config, settings.settings

i have been searching on how to fix this error. I have just changed my application to use a **.Settings** file. I have just tried to run it in debug mode and it seems to throw and unhandled exception in the **ShopSettings.Designer.cs**.

[image]

Most of the answers to other questions talk about the **Config** file which every answer i have tried doesn't change anything.

[image]

This happens when the application is first loaded... Even so that the application can't throw an unhandled exception if i run it outside the debug mode.

Thanks in Advance, and if there is anything else that is required for an answer. Please comment and I will get back ASAP.

**Update**

Here is the View Details screen. (Red marks for security reasons)

[image]

[image]

All of the errors that i have when id debug to when the ServerName is first used of which is where it throws the error

Comment: Probably the problem is, that you have defined two sections with different names, but the same reference. I guess the system can not handle this. Do you have any Inner Exceptions for this unhandled exception?

Comment: I have just tried commenting them out (not all but the ones i weren't using) and then running it and i have the same issue... inner Exceptions?

Comment: In your exception dialog go to "View Details." Probably there is further information included. Another possibility would be to add an Global Unhandeld Exception handler and grab the exception on the fly [Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/6641105)

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your SectionGroup userSettings. If you delete this section everything should work pretty good.

You have defined to sectiongroups:

- userSettings
- userShopSettings

But you only have declared the information for userShopSettings.

Comment: I did that as part of your comment. Nothing changed :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your tag from <usershopsettings> to <usersettings> and also renaming the sectiongroup?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either. I am just about to add something to the question that might help

Comment: So you have changed all namings from usershopsettings to usersettings, removed the duplicate entries from the app.config, making a complete rebuild of the solution and it still doesn´t work?

Comment: I changed the name of the settings file - Rebuild and it worked... i have marked your answer as correct because i dont think i did a rebuild. Thanks for the help because i think you were the one to actually find the answer it was just me not rebuilding the application which may have not done anything

Comment: np. Regarding your problem with release mode. Probably you should switch to release and make a complete rebuild. I guess this will do the trick. Otherwise please checkup your Settings files if you are in release mode, because maybe they differ from the actual file in debug mode.

Comment: That still only allows me to run it in debug mode... not too much of an issue so i wouldn't worry too much

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue... not 100% how but what i did was change the name to **ServerConfig** and and it worked... The only thing is that i can only run the application in Debug mode. If anyone can figure out the reason as to how this worked then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Here is what my app.config file now looks like (for anyone interested).

[image]