# Exception that handles and logs any kind of Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know if this idea is possible to implement. If not, i would appreciate some alternative.

I need to create an custom exception class that can catch any time of error, as do the System.Exception class. But on catching an exception, it would be able to log the error.

This code is my implementation, but it does not catch any type of exceptions.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException()
    {
          //Log error
    }

    public CustomException(string message)
    : base(message)
    {
           //Log error
    }

    public CustomException(string message, Exception inner)
    : base(message, inner)
    {
           //Log error
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're confusing `Exception` objects with `try-catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception object won't do the "catching" part. You need to have something else to do that, there are several ways to do this, depending on what type of application you have.

One is explained here:

https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Or:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

OWIN:
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/23/aspnet-core-tips-and-tricks-global-exception-handling/

Console app:
[.NET Global exception handler in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like [ELMAH](http://elmah.github.io/)  It will log any unhandled exceptions to a system of your choice (text file, event log, SQL table, etc).