# System.IO.File.Move() doesn't move the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a simple exe that, when opened, moves itself to my documents folder, but when i open it, it doesn't do that, what can i do?

```cs
string fileName = "installer.exe";
string strExeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string strWorkPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strExeFilePath);
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string destFileMove = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFileMove);
```

Comment: "it doesn't do that" - are there any errors thrown?

Comment: "Moves itself" - When the application is running, the files for it will be locked, and prevented from being moved. So what it is you are really trying to do?

Comment: If that's all that the program does, you'll find the reason it didn't work back in the Windows Application event log.  Use the debugger to diagnose exceptions, beware of try/catch-say-nothing code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/17034

Comment: @JonasH that is incorrect. You _can_ move the current exe as that's just a rename operation. Give it a try with a simple console app and you'll see it works even while the executable is running.

Comment: @Ortund - That's not a helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.Move(string, string)` takes in 2 *file names*, so your second parameter is incorrect: instead of passing the target folder, you have to pass the target full file name.

If you want to preserve your previous file name, do it like this:

```
string destFileMove = Path.Combine( 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    fileName);
```